# Why should I define background task as suspend function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, background-task

I have a background task in a function which returns a value. I use **Kotlin coroutines**.
I can do it like this:

```
fun backTask(): Int {
   // Might take a few seconds
   return 10
}
```

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatcher.Main){
   val num = withContext(Dispatcher.IO) { backTask() }
   toast("Number: $num")
}
```

So it works. What exactly is making me define my background task function, a `suspend function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your function with `suspend` modifier if you invoke another `suspend` function from there. For example consider the following case:

```
suspend fun backTask(): Int = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
   // Might take a few seconds, runs in background thread.
   10
}
```

Here we invoke `suspend fun withContext()` and add `suspend` modifier to the `backTask` function. If we don't do that compiler will give an error **Suspend function `withContext` should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function**. In that case using a coroutine we can invoke `backTask` function without blocking the Main Thread:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatcher.Main) {
   val num = backTask() // not blocking the Main Thread
   toast("Number: $num")
}
```

Note: `GlobalScope.launch` [is not recommended to use](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/).

Comment: GlobalScope is totally OK if your jobs are non-cancellable by design. Although it's true that you probably shouldn't want to show toasts from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use that suspend function anywhere else, it'll force you to use a coroutine. This means no accidental blocking on the main thread :) –